# i want to run this project but still in problem ,i run that project few moths ago. but i facing problem also facing interpreter issue

Tags: django

enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gb38V.png)
Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
PS G:\python\CounselingChatOne\onlineCounseling>

Answer (score 0):

Add the app in your installed_app and make sure you are in the correct directory